# Why Apache IoTDB cluser version reported `can not redirect to TEndPoint` warning?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I set the cluster version of Apache IoTDB, one ConfigNode and 1 DataNode. The cluster system reported a warning message: `11:06:07.343 [main] WARN org.apache.iotdb.session.Session - Can not redirect to TEndPoint(ip:127.0.0.1, port:6667), because session can not connect to it`. What is the reason for this writing data message? How can I deal with this warning?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `session.setEnableRedirection(false)` before opening the `session` to write data in Apache IoTDB.